# getCurrentPlace gives only 20 results and filter is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I was trying to use Places API for Android to list out places nearby me. I used following code:

```
List<Integer> placeType = new ArrayList();
placeType.add(Place.TYPE_GROCERY_OR_SUPERMARKET);
PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(placeType, true, null, null);
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
        .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, filter);
```

But I am getting only 20 results. Moreover the filter I applied is not working. There is no difference in results whether you give some filter of pass filter parameter null.

Please clarify.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 3):

PlaceFilter does not support filtering by type.

The only supported constructor is the two-argument one below:

```
PlaceFilter(boolean requireOpenNow, Collection<String> restrictToPlaceIds)
```

If you'd like to restrict by type, you can try manually looking through the results from `getCurrentPlace()` and filtering for places that have the `TYPE_GROCERY_OR_SUPERMARKET` type.

Comment: Recent google play services already support PlaceFilter with placeType, but I think that it won't work because getCurrentPlace doesn't support the latest version of PlaceFilter

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use PlaceFilter in Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace to filter the type of place. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android/current-place):

*You can optionally specify a PlaceFilter to restrict the results to one or more place IDs (up to a maximum of 10), or to select only places that are currently open. If no filter is specified, the results are not filtered.*

Comment: I agree what document says. But while exploring this API, I found this constructor of PlaceFilter where we can all these category of filters as parameters of constructor. Even if it does not work, what should be the way to apply Place Type filter?

Answer (score 2):

This is limitation from [Google](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search?hl=en):

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will return more than 20, then the search response will include an additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the next set of results. If the next_page_token is null, or is not returned, then there are no further results. There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an INVALID_REQUEST response. Retrying the request with the same next_page_token will return the next page of results.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer, it helped. What about filters?

Comment: I found that PlaceFilter not have 4 parameter from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter). Maybe you change to `PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(false, placeType)`, bro ^^

Comment: I've got this 4 parameter constructor constructor in Android Studio auto suggest code. Let's wait for google people to comment on this.